# Im trying to make a bullet script in unity but it cant convert a gameobject to a rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The code is basiclly just making a rigidbody to move the new bullet and the ndestroy it after some time

i tried to make the bullet dissapier after 4 seconds but its not working
i have tried to figure it out my self but am not getting anything working

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ShootGun : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float bulletSpeed = 10;
    public Rigidbody bullet;
    public float bulletlifetime = 4;
    GameObject bulletthing;
    
    void Fire()
    {
        Rigidbody bulletClone = (Rigidbody) Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        bulletClone.velocity = transform.right * bulletSpeed;
        bulletthing = bulletClone;
        Invoke("Death", bulletlifetime);
    }
    void Death()
    {
        Destroy(bulletthing);
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Fire();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so get the rigidbody off the gameobject?

Comment: `bulletthing = bulletClone.gameObject`

Answer (score 1):

You should check the errors in the *Console*. The line `bulletthing = bulletClone;` gives

```
ShootGun.cs(15,23): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Rigidbody' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'
```

because *Rigidbody* can't be converted to *GameObject*. It can be a part of a game object. Luckily, as @hijinxbassist points out, every component knows the game object it's attached to and you can do:

```
bulletthing = bulletClone.gameObject
```

Side note: If you call `Instantiate` with a component as first parameter it will actually create the whole game object where the component is attached to but, because you used the component, return the component's reference. Thus the cast `(Rigidbody)` is also superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

So either you need to get the `GameObject` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77145574/7111561).

Or you store the `Rigidbody` and access the `GameObject` later.

---

But actually you don't need to store it at all! `Destroy` already has such a delay parameter so you could simply do it in one go

```
void Fire()
{
    var bulletClone = Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    bulletClone.velocity = transform.right * bulletSpeed;
    Destroy(bulletClone.gameObject, bulletlifetime);
}
```

Comment: That was only destroying the rigidbody so the object would still be there just not move but the bulletClone.gameObject did work

Comment: @CoderSpek I'm a bit confused .. but yes `Destroy(bulletClone.gameObject, bulletlifetime);` is what I proposed